# cordova (kendo mobile) LocalStorage Lifecycle

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage, kendo-mobile

Me and my team am preparing to start developing a cross-platform mobile app using 
( kendo UI /cordova 3.2.0)
,we need to authenticate the users , we're considering using the LocalStorage to save the authentication status , but I'm reading posts that say that Iphones does not preserve the data stored in the LocalStorage for IOS 5.1 or later . so I created a test app to test the localStorage and it worked fine . so I am wondering if there are any cases where the localStorage fails or if IOS will clear this Data in any case other than uninstalling the app ?.

Thank you ,

here is the code that works.

```
 <div class="view-content">



                    <label>
                        <p>to save </p>
                           <p> <input type="text" data-bind="value: username" /></p>

                        <br><br>
                    </label>

            <div class="buttonArea">
                <input type="submit" id="save" data-role="button" data-bind="click: onSave" class="login-button" value="Save" />
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" id="show" data-role="button" data-bind="click: onShow" class="login-button" value="Show" />
            </div>

    </div>
```

---

```
TestViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({


    onShow:function(){
        var that=this;
        alert(window.localStorage.flag);    
    },

    onSave: function () {
        var that = this,
            data = that.get("username").trim();

         window.localStorage.setItem("flag", data);

    },


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this means old cordova versions.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Phonegap use cordova too and there is nothing about this in the doc only for BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 6.0 and higher). So it seems... no problems for you.